# Restarting CoreOS missing files

Tags: networking, reboot, coreos

Trying to evaluate CoreOS.  It really looks like it is an interesting product and I was trying to see about simply starting up networking.  I got a static configuration to work by doing the following:

Create a static network file in the `/etc/systemd/network/` folder.

It is my understanding that the important parts of the file name I drop into this directory are the number at the beginning of the file for cases when I have multiple network files this will help to determine which file is applied first and the ".network" suffix to declare that this is a network configuration file

The contents of `/etc/systemd/network/10-static.network` is as follows (yes, this is a very simple configuration):

```
[Network]
Address=192.168.1.102/24
Gateway=192.168.1.2
```

I then tried starting the service: `sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd`

This actually worked and assigned a static ip address that was visible when running ifconfig.

Here is my problem.  I rebooted the CoreOS virtual machine and noticed that the networking was no longer set on reboot.  When I check the /etc/systemd/network/ folder it is empty and my configuration file apparently disappeared on reboot.

Does anyone know why this would have happened?

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 1):

You must remove ISO image, coreOS maybe reboot same ISO image. If you remove ISO image, coresystem can reboot from new system.

I experienced the same situation before.

Answer (score 0):

Files on disk shouldn't disappear on you like that. Did you happen to PXE-boot this VM or somehow use a file system in RAM?

A better way to do this config is with cloud-config, which CoreOS uses to configure machines at boot. It's intended to provide a repeatable way to set up networking, mount disks and things like that. The steps that you completed manually can be done with cloud-config like this: https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/network-config-with-networkd/

More info about cloud-config in general: https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/cloudinit-cloud-config/

Comment: I realize that, I was not looking at cloud config yet I was still looking at CoreOS itself.  No, it is NOT PXE booted and the file system is not in RAM...